# Install Helm v3 in Kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install nginx ingress using helm version 3 on Google Cloud Terminal as follows :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 > get_helm.sh
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
```

and

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm install my-nginx stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
```

I keep getting the error :
`Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name`

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From helmv3 docs:
https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/

$ `curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3`

$ `chmod 700 get_helm.sh`

$ `./get_helm.sh`

Can you also run `helm version` after the above steps. In the semantic helm version you should see 3.x.x something like that.

The command is just fine. Are you sure it's helmv3 and not helmv2. It shouldn't give that error because you are already providing the name for the chart.

Also can you try running the following command, it's just a test to see if the chart gets installed or does it throw an error. It will generate a random name for the chart and not my-nginx as you specified.

`helm install --debug stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true --generate-name`

Comment: You are right. It is 2.14.1. I thought that was impossible after those commands above. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome yea I figured that out when I read the error. Do upvote the answer if that helped.